# Should I use "I'm" or "was/were" when talking about an hypothetical situation in the present tense?

Tags: word-choice

Example sentence:

> I fish out my wallet, gather the amount showing in the cash register,
>   and pass it to her ashamed, as though **I'm/I were** returning a
>   stolen item

I would I should use *were* since it's an hypothetical situation. But a quick search on [Google](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22as%20though%20I%27m%20returning%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8kcD2ltPbAhWUEqYKHc5HCRIQ_AUIDygA&biw=1855&bih=961) told me that I'm is also commonly used.

What's the correct  option?

Comment: The correct option is "were"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston and Pullum (2002) says on p.1152 about *as if/though*:

> The *as if/though* construction is one of those that allow irrealis *were* or a modal preterite. Where the matrix clause has present tense, we have the expected contrast in the content clause between *were* or modal preterite and present tense:
>
> > [42] *He moves about on camera, angular, emaciated, graceful, as if his body **were**/**is** weightless.*
>
> The version with irrealis *were* is motivated by the fact that his body is not actually weightless, i.e. by the counterfactuality of the content clause. The version with *is*, by contrast, presents his body’s being weightless as an open possibility, thereby suggesting that he gives the appearance of being weightless. Compare also *She acts as if she hated me* and *She acts as if she hates me* [...]. The latter conveys that the way she acts suggests that she does hate me or may well do so, whereas the modal preterite *hated* presents her hating me as a more remote possibility (though it is certainly not presented as counterfactual).

The interpretation of your sentence is parallel to the ones provided for the examples in the excerpt above.

Comment: Thanks. So none of the options are wrong. They have just different meanings.

Comment: @alex That's right.